# How do I escape strings in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am using the `exec` input plugin. The shell command I want to execute includes single and double quotes already. How do I escape it properly?

```
input {
    exec {
        command => 'curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"this":"that"}' http://a_url'
    }
}
```

This example fails because the single quotes wrapping the command interfere with the single quotes around the `curl` data option.

Any help would be appreciated, I am too frustrated to think.

EDIT - I think I got it.

I changed the quotes for `-d` to double quotes. Then I escaped the double quotes in the json:

```
-d "{\"this\":\"that\"}"
```

Finally, one of the items in my json was a password that included a `$`. I had to escape it too:

```
-d "{\"this\":\"tha\$t\"}"
```

That was not fun.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes? Perhaps you could put the json in a file and give the filename as a parameter (with @ before the filename)

Comment: @baudsp I have tried many ways, but I can't find any documentation on escaping strings in the logstash config file.

Comment: Apparently you can escape like this `\'` (Logstash starts and the command is executed). Also your config is missing the interval param

Comment: @baudsp yes I left the `interval` off for clarity.

Comment: @baudsp Are you escaping the single quote around the `command` or the single quote in the curl command? The former isn't working for me. The developers say `\'` is 2 characters, not an escaped quote.

Comment: Please excuse me if I was not clear. I escaped the ' in the curl command (like this `command => 'curl ... -d \'{"this":"that"}\' http://a_url'`

Comment: @baudsp That did not work - the contents of the `-d` is json, and this produced broken json. It looks like it tried to pass the single quote as part of the json.

Comment: Congrats on finding the solution. And now I know how to do it.

Comment: @baudsp Thanks for the assist. You got me on the right track.